# How can I tell if a filehandle is empty in Perl?

Tags: perl, filehandle

For example:

```
open (PS , " tail -n 1 $file | grep win " );
```

I want to find whether the  file handle is empty or not.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?  Are you more concerned with whether or not the file exists or whether the file is empty?

Comment: after this execution i want to find out the PS is empty are not !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) to check whether a file handle is exhausted. Here is an illustration based loosely on your code. Also note the use of a lexical file handle with the 3-arg form of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($file_name, $find, $n) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '-|', "tail -n $n $file_name | grep $find" or die $!;

if (eof $fh){
    print "No lines\n";
}
else {
    print <$fh>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although calling `eof` before you attempt to read from it produces the result you expect *in this particular case*, give heed to the advice at the end of the [perlfunc documentation on `eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html):

> Practical hint: you almost never need to use [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) in Perl, because the input operators typically return [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) when they run out of data, or if there was an error.

Your command will produce at most one line, so stick it in a scalar, *e.g.*,

```
chomp(my $gotwin = `tail -n 1 $file | grep win`);
```

Note that the exit status of `grep` tells you whether your pattern matched:

> ### 2.3 Exit Status
>
> Normally, the exit status is 0 if selected lines are found and 1 otherwise …

Also, `tail` exits 0 on success or non-zero on failure. Use that information to your advantage:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "input.dat";
chomp(my $gotwin = `tail -n 1 $file | grep win`);

my $status = $? >> 8;
if ($status == 1) {
  print "$0: no match [$gotwin]\n";
}
elsif ($status == 0) {
  print "$0: hit! [$gotwin]\n";
}
else {
  die "$0: command pipeline exited $status";
}
```

For example:

```
$ > input.dat 
$ ./prog.pl 
./prog.pl: no match []
$ echo win >input.dat
$ ./prog.pl 
./prog.pl: hit! [win]
$ rm input.dat 
$ ./prog.pl 
tail: cannot open `input.dat' for reading: No such file or directory
./prog.pl: no match []
```

Answer (score 1):

```
open (PS,"tail -n 1 $file|");
if($l=<PS>)
  {print"$l"}
else
  {print"$file is empty\n"}
```

Answer (score -1):

well ... scratch this ... I didn't make the connection about the filehandle actually being the output of a pipe.

You should use [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) to determine the size of a file but you're going to need to
ensure the file is flushed first:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $fh;
open $fh, ">", "foo.txt" or die "cannot open foo.txt - $!\n";

my $size = (stat $fh)[7];
print "size of file is $size\n";

print $fh "Foo";

$size = (stat $fh)[7];
print "size of file is $size\n";

$fh->flush;

$size = (stat $fh)[7];
print "size of file is $size\n";

close $fh;
```